# Form checkbox states not showing in POST request (flask)

Tags: html, forms, flask, checkbox

I'm writing a form in the html of a flask web app, and I can't get the request.form to show my checkboxes (radio button selection seems to work properly).

```
<form action="#" target="_blank" method="post" id="formulari">
    ...
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
          Default checkbox
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="pdfgenerat()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have my radio buttons at `...` and then this is just a random checkbox sample from the internet.
When I print `request.form` I get the radio data (in my case `ImmutableMultiDict([('curs', 'Dificultat al Gust')])` ) but there's nothing about the checkboxes. Oh, and I've also tried with text entries and they seem to work fine.

I guess I'm just lacking some base knowledge about forms, but I can't seem to find which it is.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, apparently each input needs a name. That's all then.

```
<input ... name="key_in_request.form">
```

(just realized this was the only difference I could find between the stuff that worked fine and the stuff that didn't appear in the form data)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it has to have `name` attribute and also non-empty `value`attribute

```
<input ... name="somename" value="0">
```